# Drush command terminated abnormally when exporting content

Tags: 6, drush, importing-exporting

I have installed node export module and drush and trying to export all content of type story to an xml file, using:

```
root@pc:/path/to/drupal# drush node-export-export --type=story  --file=xstory  --format=xml
```

but I get

```
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
```

similar drush command works when I export polls (which are much less than stories)

in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini  I have:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
memory_limit = -1
```

Any ideas to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: What does your php error log say? Without that we can't help much further.

Comment: where is the error log? (on Ubuntu)

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+error+log+ubuntu&oq=php+error+log+ubuntu&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7391j1j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: run with --debug.